# Make gradient paint whole object in one color

Tags: materials

What I want to do is that I want to have a shader that is gonna be affected by box. If the box is close enough to the object - the whole object is gonna change his color from purple to green. But on the half way it doesn't change the color instantly - it has this half-done color. Is there a way to make whole object change his color INSTANTLY, without this transition? [image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a way to do that with just the nodes, but I can think of a loophole. If you go to the UV editors, you can scale the UV to 0.
[image]
[image]

If you then change your "Texture Coordinate" node to "UV", the color of the object should behave the way you want it to.

[image]